# How do I add an item to sharepoint "New" menu?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepointframework

I would like to extend SharePoint "New" menu with a custom item.
How can I add a custom item to this menu ("Home" page "New" menu)?

I can use whatever works (like, SPFx, SharePoint Add-in, etc)

[image]

Comment: What kind of thing would your custom command add? The dropdown already contains all the artefacts that SharePoint can host. So what else is there?

Comment: @teylyn I would like a custom item there.

Comment: Probably I'm looking for something similar to old User Custom Actions, or the new "Placeholder" thing, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions. But for thsi specific area ("New" menu)

Comment: I'll try again:  that command that you what to put in, what should that command do? I want to understand what you would like to achieve. "Put a command in a menu" is not the desired outcome. The user would click the New button to do ... what?

Comment: @teylyn thank you for trying to help :) Ideally, on click I would like to bring up a wizard window that will take some input from the user and then based on that input create a few lists, and a couple of pages (with a specific custom web-parts) for the current site .

Comment: @teylyn for now solved with workaround - added AppCusomizer extension taht shows a banner with "getting started" button (instead of "New" menu item). When clicked, that bootstraps the application. Not exactly what I was after, but pretty similar.